# How to scrape Data from the chart in this Page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, charts, data-mining

I am looking for a way to scrape datas [from this website](https://nftpricefloor.com/it/bored-ape-yacht-club) using Selenium. I am talking about the Floor price history chart in the page shared. I unfortunately have no idea on how to scrape charts so I am here asking you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to read the data from the API URL:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api-bff.nftpricefloor.com/nft/bored-ape-yacht-club/chart/pricefloor?interval=all"
df = pd.read_json(url)

# print sample data:
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| dataPriceFloorETH | dataPriceFloorUSD | dataVolumeETH | dataVolumeUSD | dates | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.5853 | 12845 | 11.55 | 26561.4 | 2021-07-30T00:00:00.000Z | 2 |
| 5.4953 | 12637 | 102.726 | 236237 | 2021-07-30T08:00:00.000Z | 10 |
| 5.4547 | 12544 | 121.42 | 279228 | 2021-07-30T16:00:00.000Z | 19 |
| 5.5301 | 12717 | 234.009 | 538148 | 2021-07-31T00:00:00.000Z | 29 |
| 6.3304 | 15588 | 418.771 | 1.03118e+06 | 2021-07-31T08:00:00.000Z | 58 |